# Grails: How to do class.list(params) on a non-db class?

Tags: list, grails, parameters, viewmodel

With a regular domain class that is mapped to a database we can do this (let's assume the name of the class is Book): `Book.list(params)`

How can we do the same for a domain class that is NOT mapped to the db?

For those that are interested: In my grails action I am trying to pass params (such as params.max) to a non-db domain class but I get a run-time error when doing so (because it isn't a mapped domain class) basically telling me that the call is invalid. I get the data to the class through a Sql query but I am not using every column in the table. The class is basically a view model then. Furthermore, I only have read-only access on my SQL Server database (and so does the app).

Index action(throws an error since Actor is a non-mapped db class):

```
 def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
          def Actor = //sql logic to populate actor list
          def ActorInstanceList = Actor.list(params) //invalid
         model:[ActorInstanceList: ActorInstanceList]
    }
```

Comment: what stops you from building this static method yourself?

Comment: @injecteer how would i do that? The examples I found just call the list method directly on the domain class and pass in params. The actual implementation isn't shown.

Comment: another question is, why don't you define your class as a domain model?

Comment: Well i actually have multiple classes. I was under the impression that you had to map every column in your domain class but after I posted the OP, I found out otherwise. However, some of those classes would be mapped to a db table on a remote server which I have no control over the table contents. Can I still get grails to map to those tables?

Comment: no, you don't have to map everything in your db table to your domain class. In this case read access should work just fine. If you want to access another DB-server, you have to use smth like `multi-tenant plugin` where you define several data-sources. If things get overcomplicated, define a view in your DB and map your domain class to it.

Comment: In this case, I didn't have to use a plugin. Grails was able to find the linked server. Thanks for your help!